# Why does the parent ViewModel eventually become null?

Tags: c#, wpf

Why does the parent ViewModel in the child become null ?

For interaction between child and parent ViewModel, I passed a reference to the parent ViewModel to the child ViewModel.

When I open the `ManagerIndexesViewModel.IndexesViewModel` window during debugging, the `ManagerIndexesViewModel` member, which is located in `IndexesViewModel`, is not equal to zero.

When I enter a row into `IndexesView.DataGrid`, then in the `SelectedIndexCalculation` property I get `this.managerIndexesViewModel = null` (in the line `this.managerIndexesViewModel.SelectedIndexCalculation = SelectedIndexCalculation;`).

**IndexesViewModel**

```cs
public IndexCalculation SelectedIndexCalculation
{
    get { return selectedIndexCalculation; }
    set 
    { 
        selectedIndexCalculation = value;

        Debug.WriteLine($"--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---");
        Debug.WriteLine($"IndexesViewModel--selectedIndexCalculation -- {selectedIndexCalculation.Name}");
        this.managerIndexesViewModel.SelectedIndexCalculation = SelectedIndexCalculation;

        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedIndexCalculation));
    }
}
```

**Project**:  https://github.com/jhon65496/WpfFrmApp1QPublic

---

**ManagerIndexesViewModel**

```cs
public class ManagerIndexesViewModel : BaseVM
{  
    IndexesViewModel indexesViewModel;
    //. Code .... 

    public ManagerIndexesViewModel()
    {
        // ViewModel
        this.indexesViewModel = new IndexesViewModel(this);
        // Code
        // .....
        

        // View
        IndexesView = this.indexesViewModel;
        // Code
        // .....

        SelectedIndexCalculation = indexesViewModel.SelectedIndexCalculation;
    }
```

---

**IndexesViewModel**

```cs
public class IndexesViewModel : BaseVM
{
    
    public ManagerIndexesViewModel managerIndexesViewModel;
    public IndexesViewModel(ManagerIndexesViewModel managerIndexesViewModel)
    {
        this.managerIndexesViewModel = managerIndexesViewModel;

        LoadDataTest();
    }


    public IndexesViewModel()
    {   
        
        LoadDataTest();
    }

    


    private ObservableCollection<IndexCalculation> calculationIndexs;

    public ObservableCollection<IndexCalculation> СalculationIndexs
    {
        get { return calculationIndexs; }
        set 
        { 
            calculationIndexs = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(СalculationIndexs));
        }
    }

    private IndexCalculation selectedIndexCalculation;

    public IndexCalculation SelectedIndexCalculation
    {
        get { return selectedIndexCalculation; }
        set 
        { 
            selectedIndexCalculation = value;

            Debug.WriteLine($"--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---");
            Debug.WriteLine($"IndexesViewModel--selectedIndexCalculation -- {selectedIndexCalculation.Name}");
            

            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedIndexCalculation));
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `public ManagerIndexesViewModel managerIndexesViewModel` - does it need to be public? Is you convert it to a property, you can put a breakpoint in the setter to see when it is set to null.

Answer (score 0):

Your `IndexesViewModel` class has two constructors defined. One that accepts a `ManagerIndexesViewModel` and another default one which doesn't. You are using the default one in your `SwitchView` method in the `MainWindowViewModel`.

You should probably remove the default one and modify the code in the `MainWindowViewModel` to use the other one, e.g.:

```
private readonly ManagerIndexesViewModel managerIndexesViewModel = new ManagerIndexesViewModel();
public void SwitchView(string nameView)
{
    switch (nameView)
    {
        case "ManagerIndexes":
            CurrentView = managerIndexesViewModel;
            break;

        case "Indexes":
            IndexesViewModel indexesViewModel = new IndexesViewModel(managerIndexesViewModel);
            CurrentView = indexesViewModel;
            break;

        case "Provider":
            ProvidersViewModel providersViewModel = new ProvidersViewModel();
            CurrentView = providersViewModel;
            break;
    }

}
```

Then you are also creating another view model instance in the view. Remove this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vvm:IndexesViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```